# How to Find All Employees Under Each Manager in SQL if managers id is in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand how to print manager's name if it's in the same table, doing a self join.
However, how to print manager's name if it's in a different table?

I have 2 tables:

- `employee` - list of all employees (`employee_id, employee_first_name`),
- `employee_assignment` - list of all (`employee_id and manager_id`)

I try to do it like this, and I obtain only manager's id in the output. However, I want to show manager's name. but I can't use `ea.employee_first_name` since there is no such reference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee_first_name, ea.manager_id
FROM employee as e 
LEFT JOIN employee_assignment ea ON e.employee_id = ea.employee_id
```

Comment: Do another join to `employee` . `INNER JOIN employee m ON ea.manager_id = 
 m.employee_id`  and in your `SELECT` clause add `m.employee_first_name as manager_first_name`

Comment: Thank you Squirrel, it worked. So basically I can do a self join on the same table, but with a condition from a different table. That's nice!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are missing another table.

The table employee_assingment is used to keep the relation between the tables employee and manager. You can take a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guide-to-table-relationships-30446197-4fbe-457b-b992-2f6fb812b58f) to get some tips about relationships.

Please, check your schema to find a manager table, where the manager_id, available in employee_assignment, is the PRIMARY KEY.

The final query should be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee_first_name, man.manager_first_name
FROM employee as e 
LEFT JOIN employee_assignment ea ON e.employee_id = ea.employee_id
LEFT JOIN manager as man ON man.manager_id = employee_assignment.manager_id
```